# Interchange integration and summation for function $f_n(x)=\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\ln{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

My question is, for
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\ln{x},
$$
how to prove that
$$
\int_0^\infty\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)\right]\mathrm{d}x =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]
$$

---

With the theorems descried [here](https://planetmath.org/criterionforinterchangingsummationandintegration), for $x\in[1,\infty)$, I am able to find a dominant function
$$
g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}
$$
so that $0\leq|f_n(x)|\leq g_n(x)$ for all for $x\in[1,\infty)$. And we have
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^N\left|f_n(x)\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^N g_n(x)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\int_1^\infty g_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{G}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}G<\infty
$$
where $G$ is the [Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant#Integral_identities). Therefore, I can show that the integration and summation can be interchanged for $x\in[1,\infty)$.

My difficulty is that I am not able to find a similar dominant function for $x\in[0,1]$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sum itself is (integrable and is) a suitable dominating function. Alternatively, you can simply rely on non-negativity of the summand.

Comment: $$
\int_0^\infty\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)\right]\mathrm{d}x =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]
$$ holds whenever $\sum |f_n|$ is integrable. This is a simple application of Fubini/Tonelli Theorem.

Comment: Use the inequality $\log(x) < x-1$ for all $x>0$ (greater strictly, in both)